# How about adding more outside data to Stack Overflow Careers CVs?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It seems like the Stack Overflow Careers really requires you to participate in Stack Overflow and related sites.

Wouldn't it be better if it also pulled in other things like mailing list participation, open source project participation etc?

For example, Ohloh tracks all kinds off stuff that would be useful to a recruiter. For example here is the Ohloh profile of Stefan Küng, who works on TortoiseSVN

http://www.ohloh.net/accounts/Stefan

You can see all the projects he contributed to as well as the languages he contributed in.

All of that relevant experience would be great if brought into Stack Overflow Careers.

Answer (score 4):

You can already link to whatever external documentation you want.  What's the advantage of duplicating that information?

Comment: I wouldn't want mailing list participation automatically dragged in without my being able to selectively include it anyway.  And since I can selectively link to it already, there's no meaningful difference.

Comment: Besides, having to maintain it two different places is a PITA.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is it's implied that your stack overflow points will be displayed in Careers Stack Overflow. So, AT A GLANCE, someone with say 1245 points will appear to be better than someone with 72 points even if the person with 72 points is actually a much better programmer but all his participation is outside of stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't hyperlink this just like you can hyperlink anything you want in your CV? Maybe I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: The implication by Joel is that some ranking or recommendation for job in Careers Stack Overflow will be based on your participation on Stack Overflow. Therefore you'll be ranked lower if you are an uber programmer but all your participation is somewhere other than stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the kind of participation you're describing would be something to include in **Projects and Links**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want more about the **visual aspect**, not the informational one (that's why just hyperlinking in the profile isn't enough).

I don't think it's going to work, unless CV releases for example methods in an API that you create a resource, with a name and a thumbnail and it appends to your profile. We have too many online communities that can be all addressed in a CV system.